# Apache - Restrict to IP not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I've a subdomain that I only want to be accessible internally; I'm trying to achieve this in Apache by editing the VirtualHost block for that domain. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong? Note, my internal IP address here are 192.168.10.xxx. My code is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.example.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_test_co_uk.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_test_co_uk.log combined
  <Directory /var/www/test>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.10.0/24
    Allow from 127
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

You're missing the `Deny from all` line? Oh, and using the wrong `order`.

Quoting the [mod_access docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html):

> [...] all hosts in the apache.org domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied access.
>
> ```
> Order Deny,Allow
> Deny from all
> Allow from apache.org
> ```

Comment: I gave it a go, but no luck. What's happening when I try and view the site is it's returning a 403 forbidden, no matter where I try from.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your allow line for the local network. Replace `Allow from 192.168.10.0/24` with `Allow from 192.168.10.` (will allow 192.168.10.*).

For completeness, add a `Deny from all` line to make it clear that you're blocking everyone else.

Comment: I gave that a try but still no luck, it is coming up forbidden no matter where I try from. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like your config is getting overwritten somewhere, as I tested the config and it worked. Take a look at your other config files for access rules. For example, Debian based distros will put extra restrictions in /etc/apache2/conf.d/security.

Comment: This answer helped me, but a code sample would help even more. I found this in the two answers here: http://serverfault.com/a/323611/12448

Comment: Sorry hamlin11, but how could it be more helpful? I give exactly what needs to be changed in the above config example to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the path inside Directory tag should be simply **/**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName test.example.co.uk
  DocumentRoot /var/www/test
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_test_co_uk.log
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_test_co_uk.log combined
  <Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 192.168.10.0/24
    Allow from 127
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and please don't forgot to restart apache