# How to setup a git or svn repository on a local server/PC on Windows?

Tags: git, svn, server, clone, git-clone

I haven't been able to find a step by step tutorial to setup a git or svn repository on my local server/PC running on Windows! It should provide access to multiple users for submitting source code and stuff. I am new to concepts such as svn or git and would really appreciate a tutorial covering the basics. Are there any other alternatives to git or svn which can be setup on a local windows server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as long as you have apache running in correlation with IIS, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I am looking for a step by step guide for dummies, if you know what I mean!

Comment: @AmitApollo Apache doesn't need IIS or vice versa.

Comment: I'm assuming his windows pc/server already has iis running on it. They can coexist is all i'm saying. SVN needs apache, they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: As soon as you say "multiple users" you need to get *off* your local PC and onto a real server that's configured & managed appropriately, including getting backed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Visual SVN as it's very easy to setup and manage. It comes with latest version of bundled SVN server and nice UI for managing users and repositories. Free for commercial projects development.

I found very nice [quick guide](http://svnrating.com/how-to-setup-svn-server-on-windows/) for installing and configuring Visual SVN. Almost every step is illustrated with a screenshot.

Comment: this link is broken

Answer (score 2):

Set up [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) to serve your webpages and put your bare git repository in the DocumentRoot, e.g. one created with `git init --bare`. If you need further assistance, do leave a comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I dont know if I made myself clear ... I need the repo to be hosted only on the local server, so that only our developers have access to the project. It should not be on the git or svn servers. Doing what you said will do that? Also do you know of a step by step guide? And I guess there is no way around using command line to configure all this, right?

Comment: Probably is -- I'm just not a fan of using a GUI. All git repositories are servers. That's a result of the distributed nature of the system. [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) is a centralised SCM and it sounds like it will do what you want.

Comment: Here is [how to set up a git repository permissions for non-auth users](http://serverfault.com/questions/26954/how-do-i-share-a-git-repository-with-multiple-users-on-a-machine) and Apache instructions for [restricting access to a host name by IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683347/apache-restrict-to-ip-not-working)